# SEO for ecommerce site with no product description and large inventory

Tags: seo, ecommerce, duplicate-content, noindex

We are building a ecommerce with a inventory of about 6000 products, the problem is most of the products have the same description so we decided to keep description as `noindex` and make it available to users to prevent the issue of duplicate content.

I heard that it will be a big impact if there is no product description how to tackle this problem, is this true?

Comment: No content description = no content what's to index. Hire yourself a copywriter research product information to create descriptive content. Noindex = no indexable pages, how is this even going to be found by customer search? Whole thing needs a rethink if it's to be a serious ecommerce website.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no descriptive text for your products you will have lots of "thin content" pages that will not be viewed favorably by search engines such as Google.

On the other hand, if you have repeated descriptions you will have lots of "duplicate content" that will not be viewed favorably, either.

Unfortuantely, there simply is no automated solution to this. You should try to create custom descriptions for each product. You may be able to use a server-side algorithm for some of this. You also can encourage user-generated content such as reviews and ratings to increase the uniqueness of each page.

If that is simply not possible, as a last resort I would try to eliminate thin & duplicate content issues by simply refusing to give each product its own URL. Organize products by categories and display multiples per page... this will ensure that all of your pages have worthwhile and non-duplicate content. (Ideally each product has a unique URL, but if you cannot fill unique content it is better to avoid that altogether.)

Comment: thanks for advice can you recommend any plugin to create custom descriptions for word press ? is it good to do it as we can change only some words and the remaining content will remain same cause its a must

Comment: The plugin you are looking for is a human called a copywriter. No website plugin having the AI necessary to look up the information, compile it into human readable content is available.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you decided to keep descriptions as noindex? Isn't the product description displaying on the product page? If you don't have product descriptions setup product features so that each page has an ordered list of features of the product. Color size etc.

Comment: its displaying but i used googleoff tag to not index the product description cause all of it is same for 5000 products

Comment: That tag only works with Google Appliance it is not recognized by Googlebot which crawls the web.

Comment: What shopping cart are you using?

Comment: woocommerce ?  can you explain it a bit more please cause it will be a disaster

Comment: any other way to prevent indexing of certain part of content not entire content ?

Comment: Yes either remove the product descriptions, or remove that part of the template which displays the description. In woocommerce-template.php modify where it loads tab-description.php, or modify tab-description.php directly.

Answer (score 0):

It all boils down to what you're planning to do and what your expectations are (and whether they're realistic).

Your website isn't up yet, and the question you should ask yourself is: are you expecting to receive traffic from Google? Getting customers to find your website through some search engine?

If the answer is yes, then don't start with an inventory of 6,000 thin pages. It won't work. Been there, done that.

A strong domain would probably be able to rank, regardless of thin content. However, if you're starting a new business, don't let Google decide your website is low quality. Start slowly, add your own content and **do SEO wisely**. Don't regret wrong decisions. Adding content takes time. A lot of it, so plan ahead, and focus on things that you can actually sell.

Take advantage of paid advertising, combined with your SEO efforts, unless you're ready to wait for your first sale.

By the way, Google is pretty smart at detecting automated content, ie "We have the best [product name] at the lowest prices". So that approach is certainly not going to work.